# PineScript code assistance. Variable definition issues

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to write an indicator for TradingView that will plot a line > 0 in pane below if price is trending up in different timeframes or 0 if not trending. For this post and simplicity trend is defined as above 200 Moving Average.
The issue I am facing is that the variable reso seems to be redefined globally with each change and so I endup with 4 line plotting the same reso instead of 4 lines with different reso. I don't know what is needed so that each trend plot is based on separate definition of reso :( If anyone knows please let me know!

```
//@version=4
study("Multi MA Trend Filter",overlay = false)

is15plot = input(title = "Plot 15m Trend?", type = input.bool, defval=true)
is30plot = input(title = "Plot 30m Trend?", type = input.bool, defval=true)
is60plot = input(title = "Plot 60m Trend?", type = input.bool, defval=true)
is240plot = input(title = "Plot 240m Trend?", type = input.bool, defval=true)

reso = if is15plot
    "15"
else if is30plot
    "30"
else if is60plot
    "60"
else if is240plot
    "240"
    
sma = security(syminfo.tickerid, reso, sma(close,200))

trend1 = if is15plot
    close > sma
trend2 = if is30plot
    close > sma
trend3 = if is60plot
    close > sma
trend4 = if is240plot
    close > sma

plot(trend1 ? 0.25 : 0 , color = trend1 ? color.green : color.yellow, style = plot.style_line)
plot(trend2 ? 0.50 : 0 , color = trend2 ? color.green : color.blue, style = plot.style_line)
plot(trend3 ? 0.75 : 0 , color = trend3 ? color.purple : color.green, style = plot.style_line)
plot(trend4 ? 1 : 0 , color = trend4 ? color.white : color.red, style = plot.style_line)
```

Comment: @behnam-maboudi can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a separate security call for every timeframe.

```
//@version=4
study("Multi MA Trend Filter",overlay = false)

is15plot = input(title = "Plot 15m Trend?", type = input.bool, defval=true)
is30plot = input(title = "Plot 30m Trend?", type = input.bool, defval=true)
is60plot = input(title = "Plot 60m Trend?", type = input.bool, defval=true)
is240plot = input(title = "Plot 240m Trend?", type = input.bool, defval=true)

trend1 = is15plot and security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", close > sma(close, 200))
trend2 = is30plot and security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", close > sma(close, 200))
trend3 = is60plot and security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", close > sma(close, 200))
trend4 = is240plot and security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", close > sma(close, 200))

plot(trend1 ? 0.25 : 0 , color = trend1 ? color.green : color.yellow, style = plot.style_line)
plot(trend2 ? 0.50 : 0 , color = trend2 ? color.green : color.blue, style = plot.style_line)
plot(trend3 ? 0.75 : 0 , color = trend3 ? color.purple : color.green, style = plot.style_line)
plot(trend4 ? 1 : 0 , color = trend4 ? color.white : color.red, style = plot.style_line)
```

Comment: thank you @rumpypumpydumpy !